# question about complex numbers.

Tags: complex-numbers

how to solve:
$(2i)^9z^3=(1+i)^{17}$

we need to find the solutions for the equation. 
what I did that I simplified the expressions on each side by using the qualities of i to the power n. and then equalizing the imaginary elements on both sides and also equalizing the real ones, and I got that $a=+,-1$   and $b=0$. but I feel its wrong results. someone can check that?

Comment: You should get three possible $z$s for solutions, because you've got $z^3=(1+i)^{17}/(2i)^9$.  This is probably easiest done with an argument-magnitude setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use that $(2i)^9=512i$ and $(1+i)^{17}=256+256i$ therefore we have
$z^3=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1+i}{i}=\frac{1}{2}(1-i)$
$\frac{1+i}{i}=\frac{i-1}{-1}=1-i$

Comment: how did u calculate the last part? I didn't get it

Comment: this one : 
$z^3=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1+i}{i}=-\frac{1}{2}(1-i)$

Comment: multiply nominator and denominator by $i$

Comment: yeah, so from here i can turn it to trigonometric form and find the 3 solutions according to de moivre?

Comment: Funny, another answer explains why all these computations of high powers of 2 and of 1+i are useless.

Answer (score 4):

The main observation is that $(1+i)^2 = 2i$. So your equation is really just

$$ (1+i)^{18}z^3 = (1+i)^{17}$$

Answer (score 2):

I suggest converting the complex vectors to polar form, since multiplication and exponentiation are much easier in polar form.

$$0 + 2i = 2 ~\angle~\pi/2$$
$$1 + i = \sqrt 2 ~\angle~ \pi/4$$

Then just use the results that $(a ~\angle~ b)\times (c~\angle d) = (ac) ~\angle~ (b+d)$, and that $(a ~\angle b)^n = a^n \angle bn$.

$$\begin{align}
(2i)^9z^3 &= (1+i)^{17} \\
(2~\angle~ \pi /2)^9~z^3 &= (\sqrt 2 ~\angle~ \pi/4)^{17} \\
(2^9~\angle~ 9\pi /2)~z^3 &= (\sqrt 2^{17} ~\angle~ 17\pi/4) \\
z^3 &= (\sqrt 2^{17} ~\angle~ 17\pi/4)\div (2^9~\angle~ 9\pi /2) \\
z^3 &= \sqrt 2^{17} / \sqrt{2}^{18} ~\angle~ 17\pi/4 - 9\pi /2 \\
z^3 &=  2^{-1/2} ~\angle~ - \pi / 4 \\
\end{align}$$

Now there are 3 cube roots, whose magnitude will be $\sqrt[3]{2^{-1/2}}$ and whose angles are the solutions to $3a_1 = -\pi/4$, $3a_2 = -\pi/4 + 2\pi$ and $3a_3 = -\pi/4 + 4\pi$, giving solutions

$$\begin{cases}
z = 2^{-1/6} ~\angle~ -\pi/12 \\
z = 2^{-1/6} ~\angle~ 7\pi/12 \\
z = 2^{-1/6} ~\angle~ 5\pi/4
\end{cases}$$

Comment: does ∠ mean cis ?

Comment: $\angle$ means polar form of a vector.  $a \text{ cis } b$ means $a\cos(b) + ai\sin(b)$.  They happen to be equal, but not trivially.